# I got Error SpringBoot Rest APi Crud operation not Post Data In Database

Tags: spring-boot

## I have run application SpringBoot RetApi c[text]rud operation but Not Posting Data In database Please Help me

{
"timestamp": "2023-06-19T04:07:28.397+00:00",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"path": "/api/employees"
}

got this error

Comment: Please send solution

Comment: "Internal Server Error" will produce a log message in your console. That message will help you in the right direction. If not, update your question with the error message and your code so we can help you better

Answer (score 0):

Like Arie said, an error 500 will produce logs and the stack will let you know what is the exception thrown and where the problem happens.

If you need help to understand the reason why this internal error happens, you should describe what you were doing. To help people to help you, put example of your code : entities (if relevant), dto, service, controller...

Comment: Hi, your contribution doesn't answer the question and is more suitable as a comment.